# BufferedImage.Graphics2D - set the user coordinates?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am drawing in a bitmap by creating a BufferedImage and then calling BufferedImage.createGraphics() to get a Graphics2D object. I then render to the Graphics2D object.

I want to do all my rendering using EMUs for coordinated. The device space for the Graphics2D object is the size of the image in pixels, which makes sense.

Is there a way for me to set the Graphics2D user space? I think if I can set that to be the EMUs/inch divided by DPI, then it all maps through clean.

I know I can use an AffineTransform. But I'd prefer to not do that so that I can apply transforms without worrying about including the scaling due to my EMUs to pixels conversion.

thanks - dave

Comment: Why not use translate/scale ?

Comment: @11thdimension I believe those are shortcuts to the transform. So I still need to take that into account if I set something in the transform. Including if I want to scale something I;m about to render to the Graphics2D object.

Comment: There is no facility to have multiple transformations on a graphics. You can however backup the existing transform before modifying it and restore it after youre done (using getTransform/setTransform). And you need to do this in any case, since you cannot willy-nilly transform while painting e.g. an object-tree and expect the graphics to be reset automagically after rendering of an object is complete. Unless you are explicitly using setTransform, all transformations are cumulative and your painting code should have no problem with an initial transform existing.